# Catch exceptions in a do-while loop?

Tags: java, loops, exception, do-while

Can someone explain and help me fix this program.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean clear;
    int in = 0;

    do {
      clear = true;

      try {
        in = key.nextInt();
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        clear = false;
      }

    } while (clear == false);

    String stringIn = Integer.toString(in);
    String[] dec = stringIn.split("");

    for (int i = 1; i < (dec.length); i++) {
      System.out.print(dec[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I enter a invalid input instead of an int, my program keeps looping *"Invalid"* instead of giving the option to enter a new value for **in**.

Comment: you would like the loop to stop if user inputs invalid ?

Comment: @HuyVo I want it to print "Invalid" and repeat the input  if it's invalid, and if it is valid it just continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the scanner fails to find an input in the correct format, it will throw an exception and *not read the input*.

Because the scanner does not read the invalid int input, the next time `nextInt` is called, it will try to read the invalid input again, and miserably fails at it, printing another "invalid!"

So you need to read the input afterwards if it finds an invalid int:

```
// do this in the catch block:
key.next();
```

This makes sure that the next token is read.

Full code:

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean clear;
int in = 0;

do {
    clear = true;

    try {
        in = key.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        clear = false;
        key.next();
    }

} while (clear == false);

String stringIn = Integer.toString(in);
String[] dec = stringIn.split("");

for (int i = 1; i < (dec.length); i++) {
    System.out.print(dec[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That stops the never ending loop. But now I have an extra input prompt at the begining. Is there any way to hide it or stop it from showing?

Comment: @user9140248 I don't have an extra prompt. Did you add the call to `next` at the correct place? See my full code.

Comment: My bad, I put it in the wrong place. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [API of the nextInt method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)):

> This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.**

Meaning, that if it's not successful - it will not advance and will try to execute `nextInt` over the illegal token over and over again failing every time.

Try adding `next()` into the exception catch clause, it should skip the token and read the next one then. `next()` reads a String, so it does not really care about the formatting, and will allow you to advance the position in the stream to read the next token.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing to the console inside the catch, so then when you call key.nextInt() in the try the program reads the value you print to the console, so an easy way to solve this is to add a line like: key.nextLine() inside the catch and that will solve your problem.